# How to update chrome browser with latest build?

Tags: google-chrome

in my chrome browser when i see

```
      chrome://chrome/
```

it shows the chrome browser is up to date , but when i open console in developer tools i cant able to use the latest chrome (36) javascript interpreter features like

```
      Object.observe();
```

How to update this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Chrome beta channel?  `Object.observe()` works in Chrome beta (36),  you can also check `chrome://version`, mine is `36.0.1985.49`

Comment: yes. how to update and do this when i am in 35.0.1916.153 ? without downloading and installing 36.0.1985.49 version

Comment: 35.0.1916.153, so you are using stable channel, right?    You can't directly upgrade chrome from stable channel to beta channel. you can only upgrade inside a channel (stable->stable,  beta->beta...).  I guess you have to explicitly download beta channel chrome and install.  www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/beta.html